# Asyncio wait for state change without event

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have a program to read data from multiple bluetooth devices simultaneously. I need to wait for 200 packets from each sensor. I was originally testing with only a single device, during this time I was using an asyncio.event to wait for the 200 packets and then continue.

```py
async with BleakClient(sensor_address, loop = loop, timeout = timeout) as bluetooth:
    x = await bluetooth.is_connected()
    logging.info(f'connected: {x}')

    await bluetooth.start_notify(self.SENSOR_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID, self._notification_handler)
    await event.wait()
    await bluetooth.stop_notify(self.SENSOR_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID)
```

and in my _notification_handler function:

```py
def _notification_handler(self, event, sender, data: bin):
    if self.packets_received < self.num_packets:
        self.packets_received += 1
        self.decode_data(data)
    else:
        event.set()
```

however, as I am now using multiple sensors, I cannot wait for the event to be set as that will trigger all sensors to stop collecting if the first one finishes regardless of the state of the others.

I have thought about just having a loop under the start_notify for waiting for all of the packets and just sleeping for a couple of seconds before checking again, but that seems very clunky to me.

```py
await client.start_notify(SENSOR_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID, notification_handler)

while packets_received < self.num_packets:
    await asyncio.sleep(10.0)    

await client.stop_notify(SENSOR_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID)
```

Is there a better way of approaching this? (The notification_handler function has been modified to accommodate the change above).

Comment: I don't understand why you can no longer wait for the event. How will waiting for the event "trigger all sensors to stop collecting"? Won't the exact same thing happen in a sleep-based waiting loop?

Comment: No, I am creating one task per sensor but I believe the event is bound to the loop and the tasks share the same event loop. the sleep will not affect all tasks only the one that it is being called from.

Comment: Can't you then have one event per sensor?

Comment: would this be possible given the current code? How would I assign one event per sensor?

Comment: I'm not acquainted with the details of the library and the code, but I'd expect that you can create an `asyncio.Event()` for each sensor and pass it as an argument to the coroutine that deals with the sensor. Looking at your code, something like `await bluetooth.start_notify(<id>, lambda ...: self._notification_handler(..., event))`.